# How to bundle and require non JS dependencies in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an http cloud function that returns some dynamic HTML. I want to use Handlebars as the templating engine. The template is sufficiently big that it's not practical to have it in a `const` variable on top of my function.

I've tried something like:

```
const template = fs.readFileSync('./template.hbs', 'utf-8');
```

But when deploying the function I always get an error that the file does not exist:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './template.hbs'
```

The `template.hbs` is in the same directory as my `index.js` file so I imagine the problem is that the Firebase CLI is not bundling this file along the rest of files.

According to the [docs of Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs) it is possible to bundle local modules with `"mymodule": "file:mymodule"`. So I've tried creating a `templates` folder at the root of the project and added `"templates": "file:./templates"` to the `package.json`.

My file structure being something like this:

```
/my-function
  index.js
/templates
  something.hbs
index.js //this is the entry point
```

And then:

```
const template = fs.readFileSync('../node_modules/templates/something.hbs', 'utf-8');
```

But I'm getting the same not found error.

What is the proper way of including and requiring a non JS dependencies in a Firebase Cloud Function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use `path.join(__dirname,'template.hbs')`.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'template.hbs'), 'utf-8');
```

As @doug-stevenson pointed out all files are included in the final bundle but for some reason using the relative path did not work. Forcing an absolute path with `__dirname` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase CLI will package up *all* the files in your functions folder, *except for node_modules*, and send the entire archive to Cloud Functions.  It will reconstitue node_modules by running `npm install` while building the docker image that runs your function.

If your something.hbs is in /templates under your functions folder, you should be able to refer to it as `./templates/something.hbs` from the top-level index.js.  If your JS is in another folder, you might have to work you way out first with `../templates/something.hbs`.  The files should all be there - just figure out the path.  I wouldn't try to do anything fancy is your package.json.  Just take advantage of the fact that the CLI deploys everything but node_modules.

This code works fine for me if I have a file called 'foo' at the root of my functions folder:

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
export const test = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const foo = fs.readFileSync('./foo', 'utf-8')
    console.log(foo)
    res.send(foo)
})
```

Comment: Then the problem must be something else. I swear I've tried `readFileSync` in all sort of paths but I always get the same error. Even with the `.js` and `.hbs` files in the same folder and `fs.readFileSync('./template.hbs', 'utf-8')` returns the error.

Comment: I have no problems with that line of code in a dirt simple function that does only that.

Comment: This solved it `fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'template.hbs'), 'utf-8');`. Both files are in the same folder... go figure.

Comment: As for your edit, my `readFileSync` is not in the function itself, but at the top of the `.js` file with the rest of the requires. Not sure if that makes any difference.